# Fix a badly sized Xorg cursor that is clipped / truncated

Tags: pycharm

## Symptom:

My cursor looks funny in Pycharm: it's too big; the bottom and right sides have been clipped off: [image: Screenshot of cursor problem.]

## Cause:

My desktop resolution and orientation appears to be confusing the automatic Xorg cursor size.

## System Information:

- Windows 7 PC
- 3x 2560x1400 monitors (one in portrait orientation)
- terminal access to a OpenSUSE virtual machine using mobaxterm
- running bash
- Running Pycharm with X11 window forwarding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution:

Set the cursor size explicitly using an environment variable:

```
export XCURSOR_SIZE=16
```

Cursor now looks normal:

[image: Normal cursor with XCURSOR_SIZE=16]

Note that the environment variable can be set in the ~/.bashrc file, so that it is always set on start-up.

## Reference links:

- [A similar problem is discussed in the Cygwin mailing list](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-xfree/2014-08/msg00003.html)
- [Archlinux documentation on setting cursor size and theme](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Cursor_themes)